# Bounty popup doesn't float, but sticks?

Tags: bug, bounty, popup

Not sure if this is by design, but look at this:

[image: Sticking Bounty Popup]

I would think that a popup would stay in the middle of the screen, as if it was a new window, not get stuck to the other parts of the web page.  And if it should, the only reason I can think of is to view your question to see what you really want for the reason of the bounty, optional message, etc..  But if that was the reason then I think you should be able to drag the popup around like a window so that it doesn't cover something you may want to see.

This also occurs with the popup that comes when you click `Next`, and the one after that.

This may be a duplicate though because whatever I searched came up with something completely different from what I wanted.

Edit: As [Sebastian Simon said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405829/#comment829981_405829), this isn't specific to the bounty popup.  Although this *is* a duplicate, I don't think this should be closed because [the other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170125/) has lost all focus that was ever given to it.  This basically reopens the (possible) issue.

Comment: All modals behave like this. The modal not being draggable has been reported 8 years ago, already: [Make bounty Custom Message dialog box draggable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170125/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon: OK, didn't mention that because I couldn't find any other popups... where did you find the other ones?

Comment: The close dialog and flag dialog, for example.

Comment: @SebastianSimon: Oh yeah!  Never scrolled them because no one ever needs to.  Anyways, saw your comment on that post and I think that post has lost any attention that it ever had, so basically I'm just pushing the issue again.